# How can I regenerate entities without deleting them?

Tags: intellij-idea, entities

I added a column to one of my MySQL tables and went to go regenerate my entities and while it did appear to be regenerating, I don't see the column I added reflected in the model.  Does IntelliJ not support regeneration of entities, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Generation works basing on the cached schema. Do you see this new column in the Database View? If not, try to Refresh it. Also check that new column is present in the generate dialog.

Comment: No, but that did it.  Please post that as the answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generation works basing on the **cached schema**. If you don't see this new column in the `Database View` or in the generate dialog, **Refresh** the schema.